# How can I invoke Standard Action from lightning component? like opp add products

Tags: lightning-aura-components, opportunity-lineitem

I want to call this page from lightning component.who can help me? Thanks.
[image: opportuntiy add products page]

Comment: Found this online: https://www.tquilaanz.com/blog-posts/gb4i46fdfiz68xwl9qjxv7s5uvi4d5

I have not tried it myself.